# Class template copy constructor rules changed in c++20 or gcc bug?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer, c++20

I found this code below in a third party lib. For some reason it does not compile with gcc and c++20, but in all other compilers or in c++17 mode. I know that the `<T>` is not necessary, but I was wondering if some rules have changed in c++20 that make this code invalid?

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo<T>(const Foo& other);
};
```

Gcc 13.1 in c++20 mode fails with:

```
<source>:4:12: error: expected unqualified-id before 'const'
    4 |     Foo<T>(const Foo& other);
      |            ^~~~~
<source>:4:12: error: expected ')' before 'const'
    4 |     Foo<T>(const Foo& other);
      |           ~^~~~~
      |            )
Compiler returned: 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K5zec1Mqo

Comment: including the error message in the question will make it more accessible for future readers

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number your're right I've updated the question.